# Wait till column value updated in database and retun value in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, threadpool

Please review below line of code

```
int latestTaskId = _repo.GetLatestTaskID(bookingRequest.CaseId);
```

As per above code, we are trying to retrieve the `latestTaskId` from a SQL Server database. We need to hold execution on this line if latestTaskId is null in database.

As soons as `latestTaskId` is updated in the database by some other code, `GetLatestTaskID` method should retun `latestTaskId` and execution should  continue to next statement.

Could anyone suggest a suitable and performance effective solution to satisfy this requirement?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Context.Entry<T>(entity).Reload()
```

and query for the integer, if the value didn't update reload again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose. [`ManualResetEventSlim.Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289529(v=vs.110).aspx) will block execution of thread until [`ManualResetEventSlim.Set()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.set(v=vs.110).aspx) is called.

So call [`ManualResetEventSlim.Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289529(v=vs.110).aspx) before `_repo.GetLatestTaskID(bookingRequest.CaseId);`. Don't forget to call [`ManualResetEventSlim.Set()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.set(v=vs.110).aspx) after updating `Lastest Task Id` in the database.

Example:

```
public class Program
{
    static ManualResetEventSlim latestIDIisNotNUll = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            UpdateLatestTaskID();
        });
        int latestTaskId = GetLatestTaskID();
        Console.WriteLine("Latest Task ID: " + latestTaskId);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void UpdateLatestTaskID()
    {
        //Your update code
        Console.WriteLine("Latest ID is set");
        latestIDIisNotNUll.Set();
    }
    private static int GetLatestTaskID()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Wating for latest ID");
        latestIDIisNotNUll.Wait();
        int latestTaskId = 5;//_repo.GetLatestTaskID(bookingRequest.CaseId);

        return latestTaskId;
    }
}
```